# Using Lens in Haskell to modify values

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I find myself using this pattern often:

```
do
    let oldHeaders = mail ^. headers
    put $ (headers .~ (insert header value oldHeaders)) mail
```

which seems like the kind of thing Control.Lens should be able to do, but I guess I just haven't found the right operator yet. Is there a better way? Also, is there anything else I should be doing differently in this code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a chain of `Lens`es and `Traversal`s to access the inner header value directly and update it.

```
put $ mail & headers . at header ?~ value
```

Note that `(?~)` is just shorthand for `\lens value -> lens .~ Just value`. The `Just` is needed to indicate to the `at` lens that we want to insert a value if it doesn't exist already.

If `mail` in the first line comes from the state monad like this

```
do
  mail <- get
  let oldHeaders = mail ^. headers
  put $ (headers .~ (insert header value oldHeaders)) mail
```

then it's simpler to write that with `modify :: MonadState s m => (s -> s) -> m ()`

```
modify (headers . at header ?~ value)
```

Which, as suggested by Ørjan Johansen in the comments, can be written most pithily as

```
headers . at header ?= value
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Now I just need to step through it so I make sure I understand it.

Comment: (Tried to make this an edit but was rejected:) Remembering that many of the pure setter operators ending in `~` have monadic state updating versions ending in `=`, we can combine the `?~` and the modify: `headers . at header ?= value`

Comment: Couldn't you just use `headers . at header . traversed .= value`?

Comment: No -- `at header . traversed .= value` and `at header ?= value` are different. The former (which can also be written as `ix header .= value`) can only change an existing value, and will do nothing if the value doesn't exist.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I added your suggestion with a note.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I've been bitten by the difference in semantics you bring up a few times. It's somewhat problematic that both typecheck.

Answer (score 7):

You don't usually need to `get` and `put` explicitly in the `State` monad when using lenses. In your case, you can use the operator [`?=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v%3a-63--61-) to update the state directly:

```
example = do
  headers . at header ?= value
```

You can also modify any lens with a function using [`%=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.10.1/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v%3a-37--61-):

```
example2 = do
  headers %= insert header value
```